# Steam Game Launch Takes long time

Tags: steam, counter-strike, counter-strike-source

What ever Game I launch from Steam it shows up the dialog `Preparing to launch` and it gets stuck some times or takes hell lot of time. It wasnt happening previously ! Is there a fix for this ?

Comment: This is way too general. Is it only CS Source or are other steam games launching slow? What's your hardware specs? How full is your hard drive? Have any general conditions changed on your pc (new installs, new hardware, etc.)? 

Lastly have you run a defrag and virus scan?

Comment: I dont have anything in my pc except CS. This is happening after reent updates to steam client

Comment: Try verifying your game cache, via Right click -> Properties. Maybe the update has caused a problem. Doing this should fix it, along with many other problems that people encounter.

Comment: @Doomsknight That seems to have done it ! please post it as an answer

Comment: @kantu Posted as answer. Glad I was of some help. :) Its a common fix to many problems. One to remember if something goes wrong again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try verifying your game cache. To do this follow the instructions below.

1. Load Steam
2. From the Library section, **right-click** on the game and
   select **Properties** from the menu.
3. Select the **Local files tab** and
   click the **Verify integrity of game cache**... button.
4. Steam will
   verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.
5. Once the process is completed, the Check Window will automatically
   exit.

It is likely the update has caused a problem.

Doing this should fix it, along with many other problems that people encounter. If anything is ever wrong with a steam game, try this first.

Answer (score 0):

Steam verifies your login everytime you start a game like CS 1.6.

It can launch instantly or take time if steam servers are still verifying your Credentials.

You can type netstat in cmd to check that it is trying to connect to steam servers.